# Form submit not working in servlet application

Tags: java, servlets

Below are the web.xml, servlet and jsp code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class MyServlet
 */

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   /**
  * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  */
 protected void doGost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  out.println("hello "+userName+" how are you ?");
 }

}
```

JSPCode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 This is First Servlet
 <form action="firstTest">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>Username:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="userName"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td> Password:</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input name = "sumbit "type="submit" /></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Web.xml Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Trial</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
   <servlet-name>FirstServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>FirstServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/firstTest</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

when i give URL http:localhost:8080/Trial the Index.jsp is coming but when i gave username and password the URL is chaning to http:localhost:8080/firstTest instead of  http:localhost:8080/Trial/firstTest  and i am getting 405 error "Tomcat error HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL" is anything wrong in my code

Comment: You have written doGost instead of doGet

Answer (score 3):

typo...

```
protected void doGost
```

change to doPost or doGet...

Comment: Hahaha, this is great.  We've all been there.

Answer (score 0):

In your jsp code form tag you have not specified method name, and by default it use GET method, so just replace this code, I hope it will work :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("hello " + userName + " how are you ?");
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For to resolve this type of typo errors before we deploy into the server

We use @override annotation for to test whether the method is overloaded method or not. When ever you compiled the java it will throw exception. Actually compiler will check for syntactic errors etc. But in this scenario compiler treated doGost() is also a method by using above annotation at the compilation level only developer can understand where the problem occurred.

So. My suggition is @override for overriding methods.